# spring populating configuration properties, am unable to do so

Tags: spring-boot

i so im trying to populate a configuration class with a boolean value and i keep getting the below

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in example.demo.config required a bean of type 'java.lang.Boolean' that could not be found.
```

classes:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class config {

    @Value("${enabled}")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @Value("#$'{values}'.split(',')")
    private List<String> values;
```

application.properties

```
enabled=true
values=3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- Remove `@Builder` from the `config`-class. Because @Builder forces an all-argument constructor and Spring, using @Value, needs a no-argument constructor.
- Use `@Value` in the constructor.

```java
@Configuration
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
class Config {

    private Boolean enabled;

    private List<String> values;

    public Config(@Value("${enabled}") Boolean enabled, @Value("${values}") List<String> values) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Note that spring is smart enough to convert `3,4,5,6,7` to a list of numbers/strings

Looking back at option one... there is actually a third option:

```java
@Configuration
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class Config {
    @Value("${enabled}")
    private Boolean enabled;
    @Value("${values}")
    private List<String> values;

}
```

And for completeness, without `@Value`

1. `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Config.class})`
2. `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix")`, prefix can be empty
3. `@ConstructorBinding` tell spring to use constructor binder

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({Config.class}) // <-- 1
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prefix") // <-- 2
@ConstructorBinding // <-- 3
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
class Config {

    private Boolean enabled;

    private List<String> values;

}
```

Comment: why was the builder causing error?

Comment: @user1555190 updated my answer. Note that there was a typo in the constructor (option 2) was `@Value("values") ` but should be `@Value("${values}") `